# Mulesoft MEL expression not working

Tags: mule-el

Could someone please tell me what's wrong with this MEL:

```
#[payload[0].SPREMRG_RELIG_PREF.isEmpty() ? flowvars.ReligiousPreference = 'NONE' :  flowvars.ReligiousPreference = payload[0].SPREMRG_RELIG_PREF]
```

After this executes there is no ReligiousPreference var shown in the debugger and ultimately, when I return the JSON to the client, its set to null.

I'm using Mule 5.4.2.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I presume you create the flowvar before that MEL! Can you tell me the value of this expression "payload[0].SPREMRG_RELIG_PREF" ? Is null?

Comment: payload[0].SPREMRG_RELIG_PREF, in my particular test case, is Catholic. This is data loaded from an Oracle table. If there is no entry in the table field then the value is null.

Comment: Jim, the value of a variable can not be null! That is the reason because you don´t see the variable. Try to set another value (distinct null)!

Comment: Joaquin I do appreciate that you're trying to help me, but I don't understand. Sometimes this value is null in the database, but as documented the isEmpty() method should handle that. Regardless, if the problem were a null somewhere, when the value is "Catholic" it should work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Rephrasing the statement as follows make it clear for you what's going on

```
#[flowvars.ReligiousPreference = payload[0].?SPREMRG_RELIG_PREF or 'NONE']
```